# dplyr - use join as vlookup to capture some value from different data frame

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I need to capture some values from dataframe A (colname : "price") and put them in dataframe B ("PRECIO_LISTA"). Same with column "sale_price" from dataframe A, put the value in column "PRECIO_INDEXADO" in dataframe B.

**dataframe A**

```
df_a <-  structure(list(TIENDA = c("CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", 
"CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO"), SKU = c("4896 PG", 
"4896 PG", "4896 PG", "4896 PG", "4896 PG", "4896 PG", "4896 PG", 
"4896 PG", "4896 PG"), NOMBRE = c("Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", 
"Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", "Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", 
"Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", "Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", 
"Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", "Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", 
"Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", "Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm"
), PRECIO_OFERTA = c(29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29), PRECIO_LISTA = c(80, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80), PRECIO_INDEXADO = c(29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29)), .Names = c("TIENDA", "SKU", "NOMBRE", 
"PRECIO_OFERTA", "PRECIO_LISTA", "PRECIO_INDEXADO"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**data frame B**

```
df_b <- structure(list(id = "4896 PG", title = "Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm", 
    description = "Tu mejor aliado contra los días de intenso calor... este ventilador 3 en 1 Air Monster.", 
    google_product_category = NA, link = "https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/ventilador-3en1-air-monster-4896-40cm--4896-pg", 
    image_link = "http://www.lacuracao.pe/wcsstore/efe_cat_as/646x1000/4896 PG_1.jpg", 
    additional_image_link = NA, availability = 1, price = 80, 
    sale_price = 49), .Names = c("id", "title", "description", 
"google_product_category", "link", "image_link", "additional_image_link", 
"availability", "price", "sale_price"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Desired ouput:**

Data Frame B (df_b) with the values from data Frame A. The data provided is just for 1 product with SKU (id): "4896 PG".

Right now, df_b has values: "price" = 80, "sale_price" = 49. But it should be: "price": 80, "sale_price": 29.

I tried this without success:

```
desired_result <- inner_join(df_b,
                             df_a,
                             by = c("id" ="SKU", "price" = "PRECIO_LISTA",
                                                 "sale_price"  = "PRECIO_INDEXADO"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace `price` and `sale_price` in `df_b` with `PRECIO_LISTA` and `PRECIO_INDEXADO` in `df_a`, joining only by `id = SKU`.

You can first discard the current `price` and `sale_price` from `df_b` using `select()` and then join with `df_a` keeping only the variables you are interested into. Moreover you can use `distinct()` to avoid duplicates.

Using the pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
desired_result = 
  df_b %>% select(-price,-sale_price) %>% 
  left_join(
    df_a %>%
      transmute(id = SKU, price = PRECIO_LISTA, sale_price = PRECIO_INDEXADO) %>%
      distinct()
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44930332/786542), you can use `data.table` to do it

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df_a) # convert to a data.table without copy
setDT(df_b)         

# join and update "df" by reference, i.e. without copy 
df_b[df_a, on = c("id" = "SKU", "price" = "PRECIO_LISTA"), sale_price := PRECIO_INDEXADO]
df_b

#>         id                                 title
#> 1: 4896 PG Ventilador 3en1 Air Monster 4896 40cm
#>                                                                                description
#> 1: Tu mejor aliado contra los días de intenso calor... este ventilador 3 en 1 Air Monster.
#>    google_product_category
#> 1:                      NA
#>                                                                               link
#> 1: https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/ventilador-3en1-air-monster-4896-40cm--4896-pg
#>                                                            image_link
#> 1: http://www.lacuracao.pe/wcsstore/efe_cat_as/646x1000/4896 PG_1.jpg
#>    additional_image_link availability price sale_price
#> 1:                    NA            1    80         29
```

Edit: to update both `price` and `sale_price`

```r
df_b[df_a, on = .(id = SKU), c("price", "sale_price") := list(PRECIO_LISTA, PRECIO_INDEXADO)]
df_b
```

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: using data.table you don't need to make something like 'df_b <- df_b[df_a, on = .(id = SKU), c("price", "sale_price")'?

Comment: No. df_b was updated by reference without copying. This is very efficient when working with very very big data

Comment: this is something only for data.tables, right? a regular df would need a copy to update data?

Comment: That's correct. That's why `data.table` is preferable when working with big data. One benchmark example is [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping)

Comment: Great! Thank you!